# How to build aws-sdk-net-master Net35？

Tags: aws-sdk-net

when i download aws-sdk-net from https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net,import it into VS2019 , then try to build AWSSDK.Net35.sln. get system、system.core 、System.Data and so on missing ,then try to removed, it's unabled. so unable to build it 
[image]
when i try it on centos 7 with dotnet ,it shows missing framework

Comment: System.Configuration、System、System.Data、System.Drawing、System.Xml、System.Core、System.Runtime.Serialization、System.Xml.Linq all missing

Comment: system has installed net framework3.5

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.